# /dev/mapper/vg00-root does not exist

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure, lvm, initramfs

Since I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 server. I obtain the following error at boot.

/dev/mapper/vg00-root does not exist

I must use the recovery mode to manually do "vgchange -ay" to active my VG00. After this, I exit the initramfs and the system boot normally.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your question - you *did* the `vgchange -ay` already and got the system to boot; so what do you want to "fix" now that isn't already fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Steps i've done to fix it:

1. copy `/lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
2. change `ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="lvm*|LVM*"` to `ENV{ID_TYPE}=="disk"`

It's a real bug :  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/147216

Answer (score 0):

You can try regenerating your initramfs (with [`update-initramfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-initramfs.8.html)), but with such little info to go on with, mine is just a shot in the dark.

This could work if, for example, you somehow changed your VG's name or other parameter, but that is not reflected in /etc/lvm.conf inside the initramfs.