# Can't find LVM root dropped back to initramfs

Tags: boot, lvm, initramfs

When I boot up I get a screen saying:

```
Gave up waiting for root device
```

Then it lists common problems:

```
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does npt exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Then I get an initramfs prompt.

Is this fixable without a backup?

I can't remember exactly what I did to make this stop working...

(My hard disk is NOT encrypted.)

Answer (score 20):

Ubuntu's LVM autodetect didn't work at all for me either. To fix it, I made a script in

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/forcelvm
```

with the following contents:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
   echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
prereqs)
   prereqs
   exit 0
   ;;
esac
. /scripts/functions
# Begin real processing below this line

# This was necessary because ubuntu's LVM autodetect is completely broken. This
# is the only line they needed in their script. It makes no sense.
# How was this so hard for you to do, Ubuntu?!?!?
lvm vgchange -ay
```

Then did

```
# chmod +x `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/forcelvm`
```

for good measure and

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

That fixed everything, while persisting after a system update.

Comment: This is the real working solution to this annoying problem. I encountered this issue when upgrading my long running VirtualBox VM (initially built back in 2008 @ 8.04)  from 16.04 to 18.04. It failed to boot into the latest kernel (4.15.0-23) while it can still boot into the 16.04 kernel (4.4.0-xx whose initramfs / initrd image was not updated during the process). Looking at the error message in console it indicated that the LVM VGs/LVs were not activated (root found found) and thus dropped into initramfs. I am yet to understand why such a bug can still hit us in 18.04.

Comment: Worked well and restored my boot after upgrading to 16.04

Comment: On Linux-parisc(debian 10.3 buster) the lvm bug is still present, on amd or Intel no problem, on parisc the root lvm is missing and system boot in initramfs mode, your script works filne, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Try a temporary workaround**

In **initramfs** prompt type:

`vgchange -ay`

Sample output:

*logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1000" now active*

Followed by:

`exit`

If you have a LVM snapshot of root partition, that's a bug [#360237](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lvm2/+bug/360237). I solve this issue removing/deleting that snapshot.

If not your case, try [fix doing this](https://askubuntu.com/a/227370/139248).

Another related bugs: [#1396213](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1396213), [#29858](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/29858), [#1163406](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1163406)

Comment: This saved me after 2 days logged out of my machine in *initramfs* with a similar error.  Can someone explain what `vgchange -ay` actually does? and why it worked? thank you.

Comment: `vgchange -ay` in the `(initramfs)` prompt returns `/bin/sh: vgchange: not found` for me :(

Answer (score 4):

1

In initramfs, type:

```
     #/sbin/lvm vgchange -a y
     #vgchange -a y
     #exit
```

If you're unable to solve the issue, type this:

ls /dev/mapper
Now, you should have found root (like /dev/vgname/lvname).

reboot
And then select a kernel on the screen and select e to edit and paste a root value (like /dev/vgname/lvname) at:

/boot/vmlinuxxxxx root=uuid/dev/xxx.
Then, finally, press Ctrl+X to boot.

If problem repeats when reboot the server

go to

#/boot/grub/grub.cfg
at /vm/vmlinuz root=write your full lv path

if problem not fixed try fix initramfs as below

1.Go to server terminal

```
  # sudo rmmod floppy

   #echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklis-floppy.conf
```

#dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools
 #update-initramfs -u
 #update-grub
 #reboot
Execute this

#/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/forcelvm
with the following contents:

#!/bin/sh
  PREREQ=""
 prereqs()
  {
echo "$PREREQ"
 }
case $1 in
prereqs)
prereqs
exit 0
;;
 esac
  . /scripts/functions
   lvm vgchange -ay
Then do

```
   # chmod +x `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/forcelvm`
   # update-initramfs -u -k all
```

take backup of lvm2

```
    #apt-get install lvm2
    #cp /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2  /tmp
```

Edit lvm2

```
      #vi /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2
```

write Between modprobe -q dm-mod and activate_vg "$ROOT" add this line to initialize your lvm:

lvm vgchange -ayactivate_vg "$ROOT" if you not find this line

write below two line at the end of the file above exit 0

```
       #lvm vgchange -ayactivate_vg "$ROOT"
       #activate_vg="$ROOT"
```

save the file
then

```
        #update-initramfs -u
        #update-grub
        #reboot
```

Answer (score 3):

For some of you it might be a problem in your grub.cfg:

Stumbled about the same problem (root not found as lvm volume groups were not activated by initrd) today on 18.04.
I figured out that the volume groups are automatically activated if you specify your root device in the "grub.cfg" via device name

```
linux   /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/vg-root
```

where as they are not automatically activated if you specify it per UUID

```
linux   /vmlinuz root=UUID=abcd-[...]
```

Thus there had to be some script in initrd which contains this logic.

Comment: That is true (and unfortunate at the same time). See this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=566965

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup

   ```
   /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2
   ```
2. Edit

   ```
   /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2
   ```
3. Between `modprobe -q dm-mod` and `activate_vg "$ROOT"`  add this line to initialize your lvm:

   ```
   lvm vgchange -ayactivate_vg "$ROOT"
   ```
4. Rebuild your initramfs:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
5. Rebuild your grub cfg:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```

Enjoy! :-)

Comment: what if `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` doesn't exist for me?

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Make your changes in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts for them to persist between system updates.

Comment: Not recommended approach to make changes to files provided by a package. The change may get overridden by package updates or the change can be unintentionally kept (hidden), causing more issues than it solves.